# Adding new record from dataset

Tags: html, vb.net, ms-access, dataset

I am new at this so I ask for some leeway and understanding. I am using VB.NET to screen scrape a table off a website and put it into a dataset. I can put it a `DataGridView` and save the dataset to MS Access database using `Insert`. The problems occurs when I use the program the next day and new records are added. I cannot figure out how to add just the new records only. Can someone help me figure out how to add just the new records to the MS Access database and not the complete dataset?

Here is my `Insert` code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Try
        con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=O:\Maintenance\XXXXXX.accdb;"
        com2.Connection = con2

        com2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO INCOMING2 ([DriverNumber],[Name],[Terminal],[Region],[PostDate],[InspectionDate],[Citation],[InspState],[UnitType],[InspLevel],[Basic],[Section],[Description],[OOS],[Severity],[OOSWeight],[TimeWeight],[Points],[License],[State],[VIN],[Unit],[CostCenter],[UnitDesc],[HomeTerm],[TerminalName],[ShopEmail],[TerminalEmail],[TermMgr],[Count]) VALUES " & _
                                     "(@DriverNumber,@Name,@Terminal,@Region,@PostDate,@InspectionDate,@Citation,@InspState,@UnitType,@InspLevel,@Basic,@Section,@Description,@OOS,@Severity,@OOSWeight,@TimeWeight,@Points,@License,@State,@VIN,@Unit,@CostCenter,@UnitDesc,@HomeTerm,@TerminalName,@ShopEmail,@TerminalEmail,@TermMgr,@Count)"
        con2.Open()
        For Each dr As DataRow In table.Rows
            With com2.Parameters
                .Clear()
                .AddWithValue("@DriverNumber", dr("Driver Number"))
                .AddWithValue("@Name", dr("Name"))
                .AddWithValue("@Terminal", dr("Terminal"))
                .AddWithValue("@Region", dr("Region"))
                .AddWithValue("@PostDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Post Date")))
                .AddWithValue("@InspectionDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Inspection Date")))
                .AddWithValue("@Citation", dr("Citation"))
                .AddWithValue("@InspState", dr("Insp State"))
                .AddWithValue("@UnitType", dr("Unit Type"))
                .AddWithValue("@InspLevel", dr("Insp Level"))
                .AddWithValue("@Basic", dr("Basic"))
                .AddWithValue("@Section", dr("Section"))
                .AddWithValue("@Description", dr("Description"))
                .AddWithValue("@OOS", dr("OOS"))
                .AddWithValue("@Severity", dr("Severity"))
                .AddWithValue("@OOSWeight", dr("OOS Weight"))
                .AddWithValue("@TimeWeight", dr("Time Weight"))
                .AddWithValue("@Points", dr("Points"))
                .AddWithValue("@License", dr("License"))
                .AddWithValue("@State", dr("State"))
                .AddWithValue("@VIN", dr("VIN"))
                .AddWithValue("@Unit", dr("Unit"))
                .AddWithValue("@CostCenter", dr("Cost Center"))
                .AddWithValue("@UnitDesc", dr("Unit Descr"))
                .AddWithValue("@HomeTerm", dr("Home Term"))
                .AddWithValue("@TerminalName", dr("Terminal Name"))
                .AddWithValue("@ShopEmail", dr("Shop E-mail"))
                .AddWithValue("@TerminalEmail", dr("Terminal E-mail"))
                .AddWithValue("@TermMgr", dr("Term Mgr"))
                .AddWithValue("@Count", dr("Count"))
            End With
            'com2 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Query, con2)
            com2.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Captured Data has Updated Incoming CSA", "Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        con2.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con2.Close()
        End If
        ds.Tables.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you'll need to create a temp table to load the new records into on each run, then do a left outer join between the temp table and INCOMING2, where INCOMING2 keyfields = null.  That will return only the new records, and you can insert those into INCOMING2.  Don't forget to empty the temp table at the end or beginning of each run.

Comment: Thanks For the quick response Eric. I like the logic here that you have mentioned. I have not got a chance to implement it yet. I want to make sure I follow you before I give it a shot. So I am clear; In my database create a temp or duplicate table of the INCOMING2. Then do a left outer join between the temp table and INCOMING2 where the dataset keyfields = null IN MY INSERT STATEMENT? If so, could you give an example of the insert statement?

Comment: Hello Eric, I would like to thank you. You made me look at the whole project differently. I did not realize that I could send command text to the Access Data Base like VBA code. I was able to Clear the Temp table insert the data in and then move it over to the table I needed similar to the way you described. I am new at this but how do I vote on your solution?

Comment: You can't because I didn't provide an answer, just a comment.  Feel free to post your final solution as then answer to help others in the future and then you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Probably not the most efficient code but here is how I solved it.  I reused the command text to clear my temp table, store in the temp table and move to the main table where not in:

Comment: Perfectly valid way to do it bwaller.  I did edit the code to remove the extra .Open/.Close calls.  No need to close the connection between queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
        con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=O:\Maintenance\BWALLER\CSA AUTO\CSA.accdb;"
        com2.Connection = con2

        com2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM T_INCOMING2"
        con2.Open()
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con2.Close()
        com2.Connection = con2

        com2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM INCOMING3"
        con2.Open()
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con2.Close()
        com2.Connection = con2


        com2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO T_INCOMING2 ([DriverNumber],[Name],[Terminal],[Region],[PostDate],[InspectionDate],[Citation],[InspState],[UnitType],[InspLevel],[Basic],[Section],[Description],[OOS],[Severity],[OOSWeight],[TimeWeight],[Points],[License],[State],[VIN],[Unit],[CostCenter],[UnitDesc],[HomeTerm],[TerminalName],[ShopEmail],[TerminalEmail],[TermMgr],[Count]) VALUES " & _
                                     "(@DriverNumber,@Name,@Terminal,@Region,@PostDate,@InspectionDate,@Citation,@InspState,@UnitType,@InspLevel,@Basic,@Section,@Description,@OOS,@Severity,@OOSWeight,@TimeWeight,@Points,@License,@State,@VIN,@Unit,@CostCenter,@UnitDesc,@HomeTerm,@TerminalName,@ShopEmail,@TerminalEmail,@TermMgr,@Count) "
        con2.Open()
        For Each dr As DataRow In table.Rows
            With com2.Parameters
                .Clear()
                .AddWithValue("@DriverNumber", dr("Driver Number"))
                .AddWithValue("@Name", dr("Name"))
                .AddWithValue("@Terminal", dr("Terminal"))
                .AddWithValue("@Region", dr("Region"))
                .AddWithValue("@PostDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Post Date")))
                .AddWithValue("@InspectionDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Inspection Date")))
                .AddWithValue("@Citation", dr("Citation"))
                .AddWithValue("@InspState", dr("Insp State"))
                .AddWithValue("@UnitType", dr("Unit Type"))
                .AddWithValue("@InspLevel", dr("Insp Level"))
                .AddWithValue("@Basic", dr("Basic"))
                .AddWithValue("@Section", dr("Section"))
                .AddWithValue("@Description", dr("Description"))
                .AddWithValue("@OOS", dr("OOS"))
                .AddWithValue("@Severity", dr("Severity"))
                .AddWithValue("@OOSWeight", dr("OOS Weight"))
                .AddWithValue("@TimeWeight", dr("Time Weight"))
                .AddWithValue("@Points", dr("Points"))
                .AddWithValue("@License", dr("License"))
                .AddWithValue("@State", dr("State"))
                .AddWithValue("@VIN", dr("VIN"))
                .AddWithValue("@Unit", dr("Unit"))
                .AddWithValue("@CostCenter", dr("Cost Center"))
                .AddWithValue("@UnitDesc", dr("Unit Descr"))
                .AddWithValue("@HomeTerm", dr("Home Term"))
                .AddWithValue("@TerminalName", dr("Terminal Name"))
                .AddWithValue("@ShopEmail", dr("Shop E-mail"))
                .AddWithValue("@TerminalEmail", dr("Terminal E-mail"))
                .AddWithValue("@TermMgr", dr("Term Mgr"))
                .AddWithValue("@Count", dr("Count"))
            End With

            com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        con2.Close()
        com2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO INCOMING2 " & _
                            "SELECT T_INCOMING2.* " & _
                            "FROM INCOMING2 RIGHT JOIN T_INCOMING2 ON INCOMING2.[Name] = T_INCOMING2.[Name] AND INCOMING2.[PostDate] = T_INCOMING2.[PostDate] AND INCOMING2.[Section] = T_INCOMING2.[Section] " & _
                            "WHERE ((((T_INCOMING2.[Name]) Not In (INCOMING2.[Name])) And ((T_INCOMING2.[PostDate]) Not In (INCOMING2.[PostDate])) And ((T_INCOMING2.[Section]) Not In (INCOMING2.[Section]))));"

        con2.Open()
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con2.Close()

        com2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO INCOMING3 " & _
                            "SELECT * " & _
                            "FROM INCOMING2;"
        con2.Open()
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con2.Close()
        com2.Connection = con2

        MessageBox.Show("Captured Data has Updated Incoming CSA", "Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con2.Close()
        End If
        ds.Tables.Clear()
    End Try
```

Comment: For those folks of you who rejected my edit, feel free to actually read through this question and answer.  My edit was indeed intended for the op and whomever might come across this in the future and makes perfect sense if you're not just gaming the system for points. I could just as easily have posted this myself, but didn't and bwaller, using my comments to the original question came up with his own solution.  I just pointed out that there is no need to .Open/.Close around each query, and stated so in the comment on my edit.